# parameters tuning in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, parameters

I use tf to training a model. Since the initial value of the network is generally set to random, this means that even if the parameters are unchanged, the results of each training are different. How to judge that the improvement is due to my tuning of parameters or some good initial parameters? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can train the same model multiple times to see how big the difference is. However, there are some good practices to follow. Among others you can

- Use cross-validation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)
- Ensure your validation dataset is big enough to have statistical significance. If you only have 100 test images, getting one more correct would give you a 1% boost. Have 10.000 images in this set means you have to get 100 more correct for the same 1% boost, which already feels better :)

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you. if the difference is large, how to do next?

Comment: probably get more data... you are likely overfitting on parts of your data :)